# Downloading two copies of the Yosemite public beta

Tags: install, macos, beta-seed-program

Apple granted me access to the [Yosemite Public Beta,](https://appleseed.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/welcome) and I successfully installed it onto my Macbook Pro. I now intend to replace my Macbook Pro's HDD with an SSD drive and I want to make a clean install of Yosemite onto it. I tried accessing the OS X Beta Program page that gave me the code I redeemed the first time and clicked the code, but the App Store says it's not possible to redeem it again.

I have access to the iOS Developer Program, but it doesn't seem to allow me to download a build of OS X  Yosemite.

I tried searching my computer for the install program but it's now gone, possibly removed by Yosemite itself once it had been successfully installed. Not having access to the software and having no way to download again through the same procedure, I'm wondering if there's any way to make a clean install of Yosemite now that I've already installed it.

Is there any way to recover the software (e.g. could it still be somewhere on my disk?), or to download it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the App Store and select "Purchases" tab while holding <kbd>Option</kbd> also called the <kbd>alt</kbd> you should be able to re-download the installer.  Then it will show up in the Applications folder again.

Comment: I tried doing that, but it doesn't make any difference. I clicked the icon while holding alt. Is that correct?

Comment: Is the installer still in your Applications folder?  I just tested on another machine and was able to re-download using the above, but only if the installer didn't exist in the Applications folder.

Comment: Never mind! In my case it wasn't showing up because I had downloaded the item using the US store, while I'm usually logged into the Italy store (I often switch at my convenience). Using the option trick you described while set to the US store revealed Yosemite Beta 4 and I was able to download it.